# Разработка игр под Android

Tags: работа, android, c++

Доброго времени суток!

Хочу устроиться работать в своем городе на работу, хоть как-то связанную с С++. Единственная доступная вакансия это разработка игр под Android. Так как телефон у меня именно с этой ОС, то думаю стоит попробовать.

Что нужно изучить чтобы более менее разобраться в этой теме и чувствовать себя уверенно на собеседовании?

Comment: А что вы уже знаете?

Comment: Закономерный вопрос. Из того, что как я думаю понадобится, это стандарт С++ и ООП, самые начальные знания про графику(с универа). Для того, чтобы подтянуть знания по графике буду изучать лекции от МарГТУ, но там про android ни слова, зато есть основы OpenGL. Ещё знаю английский на уровне чтения тех. документации и книг.

Comment: андроид и с++?

Comment: Да, через OpenGL. Вот только где про это почитать можно?

Comment: Если Android, то надо жабу учить

Comment: Ну погодите, а NDK?

Comment: Под дроида хоть на Lua писать пожно... Среда разработки все сделает сама. Суть в том - есть ли смысл извращаться если Java является истинным языком разработки для дроида?!

Comment: как сказано на странице про ndk, этот путь не для тех, кто умеет c/c++ и поэтому проще, а у кого есть наработки, которые лень переносить на java. может уже пара сотен игр типа alawar.ru написаны, и их надо на андроид портировать...

Comment: Это не так. Серьезные игры пишут на плюсах, потому что с джавой больше мороки. Ну и сейчас обычно пишут сразу на все платформы, тут тоже больше плюсы подходят.

Comment: @IronVbif это не так. На плюсах пишут критически важные (в плане производительности) участки, все остальное пишется под Java - это и быстрее и дешевле

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почему то все начали писать про джаву. Смысл учить джаву, если в вакансии нужен именно **с++** разработчик?

Для собеседования лучше почитать:

- Про С++ пару факов по "непонятным" местам ([Хороший и известный блог](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/)) и про новый стандарт ([С++11 FAQ в переводе](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2012/05/c-11-faq.html)).
- Про OpenGL ES есть пара книжек "OpenGL ES Programming Guide", начинать надо сразу со 2.0.
- Так же стоит учесть что на собеседованиях любят спрашивать почему люки круглые ([Про что еще спрашивают](http://ahover.ru/2010/03/15_google_questions_that_will_make_you_feel_stupid/)) и математику (Дисретка, линал, матан).
- Именно про андроид есть выступления с Google IO, стоит посмотреть  Writing Real-Time Games for Android (Java) и Bringing C and C++ Games to Android (с++) ( Ссылки [Тыц](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/WritingRealTimeGamesAndroid.html) [Тыц](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk) [Тыц](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yorhsSPFG4))
- В нете [есть](http://blog.gamedeff.com/?p=64) список вопросов задаваемых для гейм девелоперов, он большой и сложный, но попробуйте почитать.

Comment: Всё бы ничего в том списке вопросов, но вот секция про ассемблер меня смутила.

Answer (score 4):

[Мои уроки по написанию игры](http://dajver.blogspot.com/2012_01_01_archive.html). Правда там `java` + `canvas`.

Comment: супер!....

Comment: Пиар проплачен?)))

Comment: @Gorets, одним рускоязычным блогом про android больше. Написано может быть не всеобъемлюще, но достаточно глубоко в предметную область с акцентом на андроид. полезно в любом случае.

Answer (score 2):

Если хочешь научиться программированию под мобильные девайсы, придумай себе тему для несложной программы и пиши. Да, будешь долго париться с простыми вещами, но так ты сможешь сам во всем разобраться. Тем более, что у тебя есть девайс под андроид, удобно отлаживать и тестить.

PS: я вот таким способом, только писал под Windows Phone, неплохо разобрался в C# и сейчас работаю шарпером.

Answer (score 2):

Если знаеш С++, то можно попробовать вкурить в Cocos2dx, движок для создания кросплатформенных приложений ознакомится можно [тут](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Сам в данный момент изучаю программирование на андроид. Тебе следует подучить Java и XML. Android- довольно таки перспективная платформа!